# Python fast dictionary creation with Pickle?

Tags: python, dictionary, pickle

I'm trying to write an anagram service. The first stage of the program is to go through a dictionary of words and create a Python dictionary with keys for the word lengths and values of the words of those lengths, ie:

```
def processedDictionary():
    d = defaultdict(list)
    f = open(dictionaryFile, "r")
    f.close()
    for line in lines:
        length = len(line)
        d[length].append(line)
    return d
```

This means that the anagram word only has to be compared to words of the same length, with `processedDictionary()[length]` which speeds up the script. However, I was trying to optimise the script even more, because it is silly that the dictionary has to be 'processed' every time somebody anagrams a word, so I looked at pickle for loading the already sorted dictionary every time:

```
def processedDictionary():
    file = open("dic.obj",'rb')
    object_file = pickle.load(file)
    file.close()
    return object_file
```

`dic.obj` is a 2MB dump of the processed dictionary. However, even with cPickle the pickled dictionary loads about twice as slow as the original script! Can anybody suggest what I am missing here and what the correct route to optimise the dictionary loading is?

Comment: Which python version are you running?

Comment: Python 2.7. Sorry, always forget to mention that...

Comment: No worries, it's just particularly important when working with Pickle :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you **dump** the data, make sure you specify the protocol to use:

```
with open('dict.obj', 'wb') as fh:
    pickle.dump(obj, fh, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

And when loading, you should see a speed increese if you switch to Python 3 (if possible).

```
with open('dict.obj', 'rb') as fh:
    return pickle.load(fh)
```

Also storing the pickled file on a separate medium would be reccommended.
Because running everything from the same device will slow down the reading process.

Comment: Thanks Torxed. Speed is much faster with the highest protocol, but are still only marginal improvements. PICKLED: ( real 0m0.168s user 0m0.120s sys 0m0.032s)  ORIGINAL: ( real 0m0.175s user 0m0.140s sys 0m0.024s)

Comment: Are you saying your pickle takes 0.168 seconds to complete? Because if that's the marginals you're working with.. they are FAST in comparison. You have to take into account that it's already fast to begin with, shaving off time at these levels are extremely complicated working with Python. You'll notice a drastical improvement if you lets say had to do more computing on the strings when reading in them in a "raw" format, that's when pickle would be useful to you. If you had 1GB of data, you'd save a minute or so, and 1GB of data isn't much either :)

Comment: Thanks. I suspected that. I just thought that it was strange that unpickling a dictionary takes the same amount of time as creating a processed Python dictionary from scratch. If Pickling does not add much speed, is it worth using at all?

Comment: I'd say pickling is extremely useful in larger projects where calculation is a time-factor. For instance, the battle between `[...]` vs `(...)` objects are quite interesting. `[...]` is useful when you only have about up to 5 items in it, after that `(...)` is greatly better. And if you have above 20 objects `{...}` will be desired. Same goes for pickling, it's not so useful on smaller data objects because Opening a file, instructing the OS to hand over the data takes a little bit of time in itself, and then you need to convert it. But everything has its time and place :)

Comment: Hi Torxed. Thanks a lot for your help. One last question - could you suggest any other method that would optimise my script? I know that you say that it's fast, but it's going to be a web application with potentially hundreds of requests per second. It doesn't make much sense to rebuild my Python dictionary every time. Should I try caching instead?

Comment: I would consider having a "active" python application that runs in the background which listens on a socket where it can take queries. Thus only reading in the data once, and then locally via `127.0.0.1` you could send questions/requests about your dictionary. Either that or i would store the dictionary in a database and use that, but it's not as fancy as having a python application doing the job :)
Normally it takes about `0.0001` second for my web-application to perform the query against a Python backend, which is better than unpickling at each request ending up at `0,165` + disk usage :)

Comment: Taking use of http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-connect.php and the example of a python server from my "server" answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21754547/python-messager-lan/21754983#21754983

Comment: Thanks so much Torxed. I got the server running and it's now working in 0.04 seconds or less.